# Returning false in Javascript/Jquery within an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, return

I've got this function to check my form:

```
function checkFrm() {
    $.each($('select'), function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.val() === 'null') {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            if($this.next('input').val().length < 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When the user submits this, it runs this code, and ideally if the criteria is met the form won't submit because of the 'return false;' bit.

However, for some reason it's completley ignoring this!

If I set a return variable at the start like 'var toreturn = true;' then set 'toreturn = false' when the trigger is hit, then 'return toreturn;' right at the end it stops the form submitting just fine... however that's not much use, as the alerts and checks I run in between are all triggered at once which would be completely overwhelming for the user.

Any suggestions please?

Cheers :)

Comment: Can you paste your Markup please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Returning false from the each will not return false from the function.

You will need to set a var to return false from the function also. You can still break out of the each by using return false as soon as your condition fails.

```
function checkFrm() {
    var retVal=true;
    $.each($('select'), function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.val() === 'null') {
                // do nothing
        } else {
                if($this.next('input').val().length < 1) {
                        //set the var to return from the function
                        retval = false; 
                        //exit out of the each
                        return false;
                }
        }
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, just added this exact answer.  I will delete and +1 to you!  My only other comment was a small FYI that returning false from $.each simulates a "break" in the iteration while returning true simulates a "continue."  I always find that's an easy way to look at it.

Comment: jquery calls your anonymous function for each of your form controls and than ignores the return code of it. (well... in reality "each" stops as soon as it sees a false return code... but there is no way "each" could tell you that it saw a false return code as it can only return the objects it had to iterate over)

Comment: Many thanks! the input is indeed right by the next... awesome reply, will implement it now, thank you!!

Comment: Nick you dont need the filter inside the next. It will only slow it down

Comment: D'oh! Just realised what I did wrong with this too... I returned false within the if statement before I set the return variable, oops! Thanks again redsquare, will remove the filter now too!

Answer (score 1):

When you call return false; it refurns false for the function

```
function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.val() === 'null') {
                // do nothing
        } else {
                if($this.next('input').val().length < 1) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
    }
```

That is not work for you.
You better get an array of selects like this:

```
var selectsArray=document.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

and work with them in a loop.

```
for(var i=0; i< selectsArray.length;i++){
      if( selectsArray[i].value === 'null') {
                // do nothing
        } else {
                if(selectsArray[i].next('input').val().length < 1) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
}
```